# Getting an error in W3C Markup Validation when trying to get a whole <Figure> element as a link in a page

Tags: html, w3c-validation, figure

I am trying to get whole `<figure>` element as a link so i wrote these line of code :-

```
   <figure>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="images/product-image.jpg" alt="image  " />
    <span class="label"><span class="rotate">40%</span></span>
    <span class="curle-label_bg"></span>
    <figcaption><span class="product-brand">Brand of product</span>
    Main Caption here 
   <span class="save-money">Save 395.05</span>
   <span class="product-price">€169.30</span>
   </figcaption>
   </a>
   </figure>
```

I am getting an error **"Element figcaption not allowed as child of element a in this context. 
    (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"** in http://validator.w3.org/ ,I have changed my Document Type in to HTML5 (experimental) in **"More option"**, Can anybody tell me why i am getting this error or where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>   As the first or last child of a figure element.

You are trying to use it as a child element of an `<a>` not a `<figure>`

Comment: Hi, as you said that "You are trying to use it as a child element of an <a> not a <figure>"....i agree but how i can solve this because i want a single anchor or link on whole figure mean with image and its caption both

Comment: Link the figure instead of the contents of the figure.

Answer (score 3):

Better to do this:

```
   <a href="#">
     <figure>
        <img src="images/product-image.jpg" alt="image  " />
        <span class="label"><span class="rotate">40%</span></span>
        <span class="curle-label_bg"></span>
        <figcaption><span class="product-brand">Brand of product</span>
          Main Caption here 
         <span class="save-money">Save 395.05</span>
         <span class="product-price">€169.30</span>
       </figcaption>
     </figure>
   </a>
```

Now the figure is enclosed within the a tag, and the figcaption is a child of the figure, not the `<a>`